# How to cancel the request of ajax in httpcontext and direct to another page in .NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .NET Core and creating a global exception handler. We creating a global exception handler in our application. All CREATE, Update, and Delete Operations are Done from Ajax, and read operation is done like normal Browser loading. So all these operations are returned as a partial view. And Some of the reports and some of the things are through ajax but it is returned as JSON.

SO I want to return to the common page when an exception comes. I tried with Middleware, But it is not working. It is not a WebAPI kind of application.

In application, if any Exception comes it is coming to this middleware but I couldn't able to redirect to the common page using ajax call. but I could able to achieve during browser loading.

What I Need is

Whatever type of request, I want my application to direct to a common page, and whatever the request, it should be canceled(ajax or on loading ) and it should redirect to the exception page.
How I can achieve in .net core. can anyone help on this

The below code, I have given for reference

```
   public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex, ExceptionID);
            }
        }
    
        private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception,string ExceptionID)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            
            context.Response.Redirect($"/GlobalErrorHandler/Error?ReturnType={context.Request.Path.Value.GetUrl()}&&StatusCode={context.Response.StatusCode}&&ExceptionID={ExceptionID}");
    
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorViewModel()
            {
                Path= context.Request.Path.Value.GetUrl(),
                StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                Message = "Internal Server Error from the custom middleware."
            }.ToString());
        }
```

The above implementation is a separate class and I created a separate static class with the extension method for IApplicationBuilder and I registered that startup as below

Registered like an extension method as below

```
  applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
```

Startup class registered

```
   app.CustomExceptionhandler()
```

Can anyone help on this, please

Comment: How did you register it?

Comment: I explained above for your question. Please check it

Comment: Anyone have any suggestion on this, please